# Stored procedure slowed all of a sudden

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which is basically inserting records to a table from selection of few table and views combinations
and SQL is like below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aka_spring_rep_sum]
AS
    INSERT INTO tbl_spring (col1,col2,....colx)
        SELECT col1,col2...colx
        FROM vw_tbl_spring bk
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT col1,col2,..
             FROM vw_tbl_prices_spring) sp ON bk.col1 = sp.col1
                                           AND bk.col2 = sp.col2
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT col1,col2...
             FROM tbl_xx) stock ON bk.col1 = stock.col1
                                AND bk.col2 = stock.col2
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,....
             FROM tbl_v) sf ON bk.col1 = sf.col1
                            AND bk.colx = sf.colx
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
             FROM tbl_bb) vr ON sf.col1 = vr.col1
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT col1, is
             FROM tbl_ss) sh ON bk.col1 = sh.col1
    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

The stored procedure was taking less than 2-3 seconds only till today, but today all of a sudden this was taking very long time 30 minutes plus and never ending and forced to stop manually.

After breaking the different selections one by one I found that

```
    select ..... FROM vw_tbl_spring bk
```

is ended up as a never ending call. Rest all select statements in the stored procedure are returning results less than 1 seconds.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_tbl_spring] 
AS
    SELECT col1, col2...., colx 
    FROM
        (SELECT Icol1, col2, ....   
         FROM 
            (
             SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,... FROM tbl_pens s
             INNER JOIN tbl_penh h ON s.col1 = h.col1 AND s.col2 = h.col2        
             WHERE s.col6 >= 21   AND h.col1 = 'X' 
            )
      ) b
    LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT  col1,col2,......   FROM tbl_pens s
       INNER JOIN tbl_penh h ON ON s.col1 = h.col1 AND s.col2 = h.col2         
       WHERE  WHERE s.col6 >= 21  AND h.col1 = 'X'
       ) p ON b.col1 = p.col1 AND b.col1 = p.col1 
    LEFT JOIN  vw_tbl_kk k ON p.col1 = k.col1 AND p.col1 = k.col2
```

Again filtering the different selections inside this view found out that the last left join is slowing things down
If we removed  the last left join ie

```
LEFT JOIN  vw_tbl_kk k ON p.col1 = k.col1 AND p.col1 = k.col2
```

Everything will be as normal ie will return results in less than 2-3 seconds

Unable to find what is the reason behind this sudden slowness

The same behaviour occurred a few months back and that time try to delete and recreate all associated views and stored procedure and then the issue was resolved. But this time this also didn't help

Any way to check what is causing this slowness in SQL Server?

Comment: In my experience, this is due to the execution plan changing.  Hints -- particularly `join` hints -- may help prevent this (as would fixing the execution plan).

Comment: Inspecting the execution plan will point you to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a 6-way join. This means that if there are n rows that join in each joined table, there will be n<sup>6</sup> resulting rows to insert. To highlight the exponential growth this causes:

```
rows in each table that join | number of resultant rows
1                            |         1
2                            |        64
3                            |       729
4                            |     4,096
10                           | 1,000,000
```

There are probably suddenly more joining rows in the tables, not only making it slower, but also hitting the logging high water mark, which means the database must rollback the transaction, which is typically *very* slow.